# Error starting smbd.service

Tags: samba

I am using my headless raspberri pi 4 running raspbian as a samba fileserver. It resides on my desktop (furniture).
Unfortunately, while I left my office, somebody by mistake pulled the plug.
After restart, I get the following error message when trying to start the smbd service:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Documents $ sudo systemctl status smbd.service
● smbd.service - Samba SMB Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/smbd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2021-11-11 13:34:17 GMT; 2min 37s ago
     Docs: man:smbd(8)
           man:samba(7)
           man:smb.conf(5)
  Process: 351 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/samba/update-apparmor-samba-profile (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 352 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/smbd --foreground --no-process-group $SMBDOPTIONS (code=exited, status=127)
 Main PID: 352 (code=exited, status=127)

Nov 11 13:34:16 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Samba SMB Daemon...
Nov 11 13:34:17 raspberrypi smbd[352]: /usr/sbin/smbd: error while loading shared libraries: libkr"5salba.sg.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Nov 11 13:34:17 raspberrypi systemd[1]: smbd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=127/n/a
Nov 11 13:34:17 raspberrypi systemd[1]: smbd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 11 13:34:17 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start Samba SMB Daemon.
```

Does this point to a corrupted filesystem? Are there other solutions than reinstalling?

Comment: `libkr"5salba.sg.0` looks like a modified library file name. Maybe the file `/usr/sbin/smbd` is corrupt. Try uninstalling and reinstalling Samba.

Comment: Restore from your backup.

Comment: @Bodo You are right. Unfortunately  `sudo apt-get update` gives a segmentation fault...so the sd card seams to have taken a hit...I will have to reinstall....My backup is rather dated, so I will make a clean install. Hope samba configuration and headless ssh config is still at the same places...the rest is rather standard.